# AWS API Gateway - Integration Response body mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

In AWS API Gateway Integration Response body mapping I have following code:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$.Item'))
[
#foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Events)
 {
  "id": $elem.id,
  "from" : $elem.from,
  "to" : $elem.to,
  "spent" : $elem.spent,
  #if("$!elem.comment" != "")
    "comment": $elem.comment,    
  #end
  "project" : {
    "id" : $elem.project.id,
    "number" : $elem.project.number,
    "name" : $elem.project.name
  }
  }
#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
]
```

The data comes from a lambda functions which queries a DynamoDB Table

API gateway returns the data like this:

```
[
 {
  "id": 123443214,
  "from" : 19:34,
  "to" : 22:30,
  "spent" : 02:56,
    "project" : {
    "id" : 4321,
    "number" : CIB,
    "name" : Backend
  }
  }
, {
  "id": 12341234,
  "from" : 19:34,
  "to" : 22:30,
  "spent" : 02:56,
    "project" : {
    "id" : 12341234,
    "number" : CIB,
    "name" : Backend
  }
  }
]
```

So it it's already formatted. How do I get APi Gateway to return the response unformatted? So that it's just pure json, without break lines, indentations etc.?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Small preliminary remark: you are missing some quotes around JSON string  values).

It's possible to remove line breaks using `##` and indentation using `#**#`, as follow, but the template will look a bit ugly:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$.Item'))##
[##
#foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Events)##
{##
#**#"id":$elem.id,##
#**#"from": $elem.from,##
#**#"to":$elem.to,##
#**#"spent":$elem.spent,##
#if("$!elem.comment" != "")##
#*  *#"comment":$elem.comment,##
#end##
#**#"project":{##
#**#"id":$elem.project.id,##
#**#"number":"$elem.project.number",##
#**#"name":"$elem.project.name"##
}##
}##
#if($foreach.hasNext),#end##
#end##
]##
```

Since the only reason the indentation is in here at first is readability of the template, I would go another direction.

For instance, you can add a post-processing tidy formatter in your View servlet) using [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java):

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
  ....
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
getVelocityView().merge(template, context, writer);
String compactJSON = new JSONObject(writer.toString()).toString();
response.getWriter().write(compactJSON);
```

**But** this will only work for small JSON files since the response is buffered into memory, so let's keep on searching for a more elegant solution.

The way to go is to *pre-process* your template, using a custom ResouceLoader.

**CompactJSONResourceLoader.java**

```
package my.custom.loader;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ResourceLoader;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ResourceLoaderFactory;

public class CompactJSONResourceLoader extends ResourceLoader
{
    protected ResourceLoader innerLoader = null;

    @Override
    public void init(ExtendedProperties configuration)
    {
        try
        {
            String innerLoaderID = configuration.getString("innerLoader") + ".resource.loader";
            String innerLoaderClass = rsvc.getConfiguration().getString(innerLoaderID + ".class");
            innerLoader = ResourceLoaderFactory.getLoader(rsvc, innerLoaderClass);
            ExtendedProperties innerConfiguration = rsvc.getConfiguration().subset(innerLoaderID);
            innerLoader.commonInit(rsvc, innerConfiguration);
            innerLoader.init(innerConfiguration);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error("could not initialize CompactJSONResourceLoader inner loader", e);
        }
    }

    protected class CompactJSONInputStream extends InputStream
    {
        InputStream innerStream = null;
        boolean insideQuotes = false;

        public CompactJSONInputStream(InputStream innerStream)
        {
            this.innerStream = innerStream;
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException
        {
            int ch;
            do
            {
                ch = innerStream.read();
                if (insideQuotes)
                {
                    if (ch == '"') insideQuotes = false;
                    break;
                }
                else if (!Character.isWhitespace(ch))
                {
                    if (ch == '"') insideQuotes = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (ch != -1);
            return ch;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getResourceStream(String source) throws ResourceNotFoundException
    {
        return new CompactJSONInputStream(innerLoader.getResourceStream(source));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSourceModified(Resource resource)
    {
        return innerLoader.isSourceModified(resource);
    }

    @Override
    public long getLastModified(Resource resource)
    {
        return innerLoader.getLastModified(resource);
    }
}
```

And you would then need to configure Velocity with the following properties:

```
resource.loader = compact
compact.resource.loader.class = my.custom.loader.CompactJSONResourceLoader
```

compact.resource.loader.innerLoader = file

(you would replace `file` with the resource loader you are currently using, of course).

Comment: I shall add that the proposed custom ResourceLoader is meant for the Velocity 1.7 API. If you're using Velocity 2.0, you'll need to adapt the source so that it works directly with Readers instead of InputStreams.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer! I use NodeJs so this ResourceLoader may not be available. But with the missing quotes around my JSON string values it's just working fine... What a silly mistake of myself

Comment: This question should maybe have been tagged `velocity.js` rather than `velocity`, then. But whatever, it was interesting answering and I'm glad, it's my first velocity.js velocity accepted answer!

Comment: How do you configure AWS API Gateway to use this? Without using Lambda Proxy integration.

Comment: @Paya Then you are stuck with the ugly comments solution.